# MDX query creating verbose xml style field names in dataset in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssas, mdx, xmla

I just pasted a query (which works in SSMS) into a new dataset in VS.net/BIDS

However, the field/column names returned are all showing values like:

```
ID__xml_version__1_0__encoding__utf_8____Field_xmlns_xsi__http___www_w3_org_2001_XMLSchema_instance__xmlns_xsd__http___www_w3_org_2001_XMLSchema__xsi_type__Level__UniqueName___...
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way SSAS produces XMLA. IMHU no real way to fix it.

Comment: so you have to manually edit the column names it would appear

Comment: actually XMLA is going to add a lot of additional info to the XML no a lot of free room left.